# Error: "Could not start Default Compiler: XeLaTeX"

Tags: compiling

Yesterday TexStudio worked fine, but today when I try to compile any document I get a "Could not start Default Compiler: XeLaTeX" error.

```
\documentclass[11pt][openany]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Huge \textbf{\textsf{ABSTRACT}}\\[15pt]
\huge \noindent \textsf{\textbf{Optogenetic strategies for stimulus responsive viral gene delivery}}\\[15pt]
\textsf{by}\\[15pt]
\textbf{\textsf{Eric Jordan Gomez}}

\end{document}
```

Is there any solution to this? I couldn't find a question where has already been asked.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! Please post a MWE (minimal working example) of a document which you have tried to compile.  Also, give an idea of your working environment, mac, windows, linux etc. and your flavor of TeX, miktex, texlive, etc.

Comment: Here is an example of what I am trying to compile, although anything I try to compile, however simple, fails with the same error:                                      \documentclass[11pt][openany]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Huge \textbf{\textsf{ABSTRACT}}\\[15pt]
\huge \noindent \textsf{\textbf{Optogenetic strategies for stimulus responsive viral gene delivery}}\\[15pt]
\textsf{by}\\[15pt]
\textbf{\textsf{Eric Jordan Gomez}}

\end{document}

Comment: Put that into your question.  Indent 4 spaces each line to indicate that it is code.  Are you on a windows machine?

Comment: You're missing an `\end{center}` is the first thing I notice.

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, it started working again after I re-opened TeXstudio and pasted my code into a new untitled file. But if I try to open and compile the original save file with the same exact code, I get the "could not start default compiler error" again. Not sure why that happens.

Comment: Which flavor of Windows? Glad that the problem resolved itself.